# How to create a size-adjusted community graph with eigenvector centrality bubles

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

Given this:

```
ClearAll[vl, el, ew, g, evc, valueAdded, community, sizeCommVA];

vl = {"stel", "segw", "ma7", "str1", "str3", "str2", "swhl", "sest", 
   "min", "sfin", "scst", "ma12", "shot", "ma8", "soth", "srtl", 
   "ma15", "ma6", "str4", "sbus", "ma13"};

el = {"stel" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "stel" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7", 
   "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "str1", 
   "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", "segw" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", 
   "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "stel", "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "sest", 
   "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "min", "swhl" \[DirectedEdge] "sfin", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma12", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", 
   "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7", "scst" \[DirectedEdge] "soth", 
   "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl", 
   "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "ma15", "srtl" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", 
   "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "segw", "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "str4", 
   "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", "str1" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7", 
   "sest" \[DirectedEdge] "swhl", "sest" \[DirectedEdge] "srtl", 
   "ma12" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", "ma12" \[DirectedEdge] "ma15", 
   "ma12" \[DirectedEdge] "soth", "shot" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", 
   "str4" \[DirectedEdge] "scst", "str4" \[DirectedEdge] "ma12", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "srtl", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str4", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", 
   "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", "ma15" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", 
   "ma8" \[DirectedEdge] "str1", "ma8" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "min" \[DirectedEdge] "sest", "min" \[DirectedEdge] "soth", 
   "sbus" \[DirectedEdge] "sest", "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "shot", 
   "sfin" \[DirectedEdge] "ma6", "ma6" \[DirectedEdge] "ma8", 
   "ma6" \[DirectedEdge] "min", "ma6" \[DirectedEdge] "ma13", 
   "str3" \[DirectedEdge] "sbus", "str3" \[DirectedEdge] "str2", 
   "ma13" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", "str2" \[DirectedEdge] "str3", 
   "ma7" \[DirectedEdge] "ma13", "soth" \[DirectedEdge] "ma7"};

ew = {0.01313, 0.0139, 0.0131, 0.0188, 0.01145, 0.01842, 0.01786, 
   0.01203, 0.0137, 0.0188, 0.018, 0.01561, 0.01544, 0.01767, 0.0174, 
   0.0133, 0.0184, 0.0126, 0.01724, 0.0126, 0.0139, 0.010414`, 0.0169,
    0.01498, 0.01736, 0.01832, 0.01211, 0.011911, 0.01586`, 0.01863, 
   0.01653, 0.01533, 0.0129, 0.0121, 0.01144, 0.014, 0.01109, 0.0172, 
   0.01267, 0.0171, 0.0150, 0.01192, 0.01428, 0.017406, 0.0109, 
   0.017892, 0.01338, 0.017794, 0.01095, 0.0187, 0.0155, 0.0142, 
   0.01422, 0.01125, 0.015559, 0.01788};

g = Graph[vl, el, EdgeWeight -> ew];

evc = EigenvectorCentrality[g];
SeedRandom[45];   valueAdded = 
 Thread[vl -> RandomInteger[{1, 100}, Length[vl]]];
community = FindGraphCommunities[g];
sizeCommVA = Total[community /. valueAdded, {2}];
```

Create a community graph:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

I want to set the size of each community area to `sizeCommVA` and label each community with `sizeCommVA` (like C1 = 234, C2=546 etc.) and set each vertex size to `evc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
normalizedCSizes = Normalize[sizeCommVA, Total];

communityColors = 
  GraphComputation`GraphInformationDump`$AutomaticColorList[[;; Length @ community]];

vertexSizes = AssociationThread[vl, evc];
```

Define a function for post-processing `CommunityGraphPlot` output to resize community regions:

```
reSizeRegions[scale_ : 1] := ReplaceAll[
   {EdgeForm[ef_], dir___, fc_FilledCurve} :> 
   {EdgeForm[ef /. AbsoluteThickness[at_] :>  AbsoluteThickness[20 scale at]], 
    dir, 
    Scale[fc, {1 + #, 1 + #} & @
       First @ Cases[ef, AbsoluteThickness[at_] :> scale at, All]]}];
```

First, create a plot using `normalizedCSizes`  to set the `AbsoluteThickness` of community boundaries:

```
cgp = CommunityGraphPlot[g, ImageSize -> Large, ImagePadding -> 20, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   VertexSize -> {v_ :> 10 vertexSizes[v]},
   CommunityRegionStyle -> (Opacity[.1, #] & /@ communityColors), 
   CommunityBoundaryStyle -> 
   (MapThread[{AbsoluteThickness[ #], Opacity[.5], #2} &]@
     {Rescale[normalizedCSizes], communityColors})];
```

Post-process `cgp` using `reSizeRegions` to set the sizes and boundary thicknesses of community regions:

```
Row[{cgp, reSizeRegions[] @ cgp}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Play with different values of the argument `scale`:

```
Row[Labeled[Show[reSizeRegions[#]@cgp, ImageSize -> Medium], 
      Style[PromptForm["scale", #], 16], Top] & /@ {1/3, 1/2, 2/3}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much...I think that `CommunityRegionStyle` in  `cap` should have `communityColors` instead of `colors`. It seems that it is a typo.

Answer (score 3):

A limited, partial solution using [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html)

```
legends = (StringForm["C``\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]``", #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@
    Transpose[{Range[4], sizeCommVA}]);

CommunityGraphPlot[g,
  VertexLabels -> "Name",
  CommunityBoundaryStyle -> ({#, Thick} & /@ {Hue[0, 1, 0.8], 
      Hue[0.14, 1, 0.9], Hue[0.8, 0.6, 0.8], Hue[0.07, 1, 1]}),
  PlotLegends -> Placed[legends, {.85, .85}],
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]